# Where can I find the code that defines what StorageKind the Offchain Index uses by default?

Tags: storage

I see the `OffchainIndex` interface defined here:

```
pub trait OffchainIndex {
    /// Write a key value pair to the Offchain DB database in a buffered fashion.
    fn set(&mut self, key: &[u8], value: &[u8]) {
        self.set_offchain_storage(key, Some(value));
    }

    /// Remove a key and its associated value from the Offchain DB.
    fn clear(&mut self, key: &[u8]) {
        self.set_offchain_storage(key, None);
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9d79daaa782f41680ada04719151371a737c6fb/primitives/io/src/lib.rs#L1042

And I can call the Offchain Index like so:

```
fn offchain_index_set() {
    sp_io::offchain_index::set(b"k", b"v");
}
```

AFAIU, Offchain Index uses persistent storage. Where is this specified in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_core::offchain::storage implements the trait DbExternalities which includes a set of functions for accessing the OffchainDB, in those functions you can declare which kind of storage you are working with.

You will interact with the Offchain Externalities through the interface provided in sp_io, for this case you can set your storage and declare the `StorageKind` using [`local_storage_set`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/io/src/lib.rs#L1120)

```
/// Sets a value in the local storage.
///
/// Note this storage is not part of the consensus, it's only accessible by
/// offchain worker tasks running on the same machine. It IS persisted between runs.
fn local_storage_set(&mut self, kind: StorageKind, key: &[u8], value: &[u8]) {
    self.extension::<OffchainDbExt>()
        .expect(
            "local_storage_set can be called only in the offchain call context with
            OffchainDb extension",
         )
        .local_storage_set(kind, key, value)
    }
```

sp_core [DbExternalities trait](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/core/src/offchain/mod.rs#L635)

For `OffChainIndex` as your ask, I would say the default `StorageKind` is `PERSISTENT` but I would need to research a bit to confirm or deny this. Would edit this answer for clarifications.

Comment: ah ok so it is in `OffchainDbExt` where it is set to persistent, here: [pub fn new<O: DbExternalities + 'static>(offchain: O) {}](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/primitives/core/src/offchain/mod.rs#L735) thanks!